According to the Jehovah's Witnesses who believe Jesus is a created being how do they address 2 Corinthians 5:17?
"Therefore if any man is in Christ, he is a new creation; old things have passed away; behold all things have become new." When or at what point did Jesus Christ become a new creation and why was it necessary for Him to become a new creation?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

It is unarguable that Jehovah's Witnesses teach as one of their most fundamental doctrines that Jesus was a created creature - the first thing Jehovah created. They do maintain that he was unique in various ways, so it is incorrect for anybody to think that they believe Jesus was a human being just like the rest of us. However this question is confined to asking how, in light of their doctrine of Jesus being created, they address 2 Corinthians 5:17, and I will confine my answer to that alone.
The answer is very simple and obviously seen when one reads their New World Translation of that verse, namely:

"Consequently if anyone is in union with Christ, he is a new
creation; the old things passed away." 2 Cor. 5:17 NWT, from their KIT
1969 edition - bold emphasis mine

The reason why I used their Kingdom Interlinear Translation of the Greek Scriptures (KIT) is that the Greek text (of Westcott & Hort) clearly shows that "union with" does not appear in the Greek. It has had to be added by the NWT Translation Committee in order to "deal with" the problem of the actual verse that they see. They do not see any problem with that verse in relation to Jesus being a created creature (as they maintain.) And neither do all the Christians I know who reject that view. That verse only speaks of sinful humans coming to saving faith as then being "in Christ", thus "a new creation".
The reason why Jehovah's Witnesses have changed the verse in light of the problem they see, is due to another fundamental doctrine that only 144,000 people can ever be described as being "in Christ". That is why they have inserted "union with" between "in" and "Christ". This allows them to encourage millions of people without the indwelling anointing of the Holy Spirit to still think of themselves as being Christians, who are "new creatures". They do not so much "address" the verse as "deal with it" by changing it to fit in with their doctrines. But they see no problem with it as it might relate to Jesus being a created creature.

The problem was far more obscure than I could have known without this specialist knowledge. Up-voted +1.

I am horrified to learn that JS Witnesses believe that only 144 000 people can be saved when there are billions of Christians across the globe

@SoFewAgainstSoMany  No, actually, they say millions can be saved because of a two-tier-level: the 144,000 who will get to heaven and million of others who can hope to live forever on a paradise earth. Saved, but with a different calling. And billions of the resurrected will also get a chance to live forever on a paradise earth. Also saved, eventually. It's a complex belief system.

The 144 000 are Jews and 12000 from each of the twelve tribes of Israel and interpret this to mean these are the Jewish saints Jesus rose from the dead after he rose from the dead, who appeared to many in Jerusalem

@SoFewAgainstSoMany That's not the JW take on the matter. But as this is veering off-topic I will leave it at that. I'm only out to answer the narrow remit of the Q.

I think you got JWs not quite right here Anne. Check out the NWT Study Notes on 2Cor 5:17, and you'll see that they agree that it literally says "in" in Greek. There is no difference in their view of being "in" or "in union with" Christ. Furthermore, check Thayer's Lexicon on "en" in Greek (Strong's 1722) - notably 6b, and you'll see that "in union with" is not added as you claim, but in fact an acceptable translation of the term in this context. There is no change of the verse done in the NWT.

Pointing out the translation difference is interesting but I don’t think very important to figuring out what OP is asking sometimes it is best to wait until the q is clarified before answering. I still ask; How does the belief that Jesus was not eternally existing but created as a mighty spirit untold eons ago impact the words in 2cor 5:16&17? Irregardless the Bible translation used.  In other words if the NWT did not exist does this post answer the question?

@Mason Wheeler.  Can you please tell me on what basis my answer was deleted?

@Mr.Bond https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/.  Ask about the deletion on meta
